# Why is there no difference in ++foo and foo++ when the ++ operator is overloaded?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post-increment Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668763/post-increment-operator-overloading)
>   [Why are Postfix ++/— categorized as primary Operators in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049368/why-are-postfix-categorized-as-primary-operators-in-c)

I saw that I can overload the `++` and `--` operators.
Usually you use these operators by 2 ways. Pre and post increment/deccrement an int
Example:

```
int b = 2; 
//if i write this
Console.WriteLine(++b); //it outputs 3
//or if i write this
Console.WriteLine(b++); //outpusts 2
```

But the situation is a bit different when it comes to operator overloading:

```
    class Fly
    {
        private string Status { get; set; }

        public Fly()
        {
            Status = "landed";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "This fly is " + Status;
        }

        public static Fly operator ++(Fly fly)
        {
            fly.Status = "flying";
            return fly;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fly foo = new Fly();

        Console.WriteLine(foo++); //outputs flying and should be landed
        //why do these 2 output the same?
        Console.WriteLine(++foo); //outputs flying
    }
```

My question is why do these two last lines output the same thing? And more specifically why does the first line(of the two) output `flying`?

---

Solutions is to change the operator overload to:

```
        public static Fly operator ++(Fly fly)
        {
            Fly result = new Fly {Status = "flying"};
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531829/how-to-overload-postfix-and-prefix-operator-in-c-sharp which is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668763/post-increment-operator-overloading

Comment: As a general rule, overloaded operators should always return a new instance, not modify the current instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between prefix and postfix `++` is that the value of `foo++` is the value of `foo` before calling the `++` operator, whereas `++foo` is the value that the `++` operator returned.  In your example these two values are the same since the `++` operator returns the original `fly` reference.  If instead it returned a *new* "flying" Fly then you would see the difference you expect.

Comment: oh I got it now that's because I'm working with reference variables. What if Fly was not a class but struct? Then what I have written should work right?

Comment: @Bosak It has nothing to do with whether it's a reference type or a value type.  It has everything to do with whether it's mutable or immutable.  If `Fly` was immutable (even as a class) then this would be fine.  If it was a mutable struct, or a struct with fields that were references, you could potentially have problems.